# Hashtable's Value doesn't increaing

Tags: java, hashtable

The following Java code:

```
public class TestCSVDataToMap {

    public static Hashtable<String, Integer> testTable = new Hashtable<>();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String symbol = "0";
            if(testTable.contains(symbol)) {
                int value = testTable.get(symbol);
                value++;
                testTable.put(symbol, value);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("dash!");
                testTable.put(symbol, 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(testTable);
    }
}
```

has the output:

```
dash!
dash!
dash!
dash!
{0=1}
```

Why didn't the value of key '0' grow when the .csv files were parsed? In the testTable(a Hashtable), it is initialized with (0,1), and the value should keep growing, since the symbol is always detected as a key of '0'.

Comment: What is the contents of "test.csv"?

Comment: @rgettman You don't need it, the programs output is enough to see the problem (where is line actually used while parsing?)

Comment: just multiple lines of data, this is not the issue, i just use this to make the 'while' logic continues for several times.

Comment: @msrd0 You're right; I found the problem; `contains` vs `containsKey`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), which determines if the argument exists as a value in the `Hashtable`, not as a key.  Because it's not found, you are `put`ting `1` over and over.

Use [`containsKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) instead, which determines if the argument exists as a key.

```
if(testTable.containsKey(symbol)){
```

Answer (score 0):

`contains` checks for HashTable value. In this case you want to check keys so use for `containsKey`.